# How to assign values to the elements of an array?

Tags: c

I don't know what's happening. It shows me that abc is as I expected, but when I try to assigns some values of abc to pass, it shows me`enter code here` an unexpected "4" to the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char abc[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        if (i < 26)
        {
            abc[i] = 'a' + i;
        }
        else
        {
            abc[i] = 'A' + i - 26;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", abc);
    char pass[2];
    pass[0] = abc[3];
    printf("%s\n", pass);
    pass[1] = abc[1];
    printf("%s\n", pass);
}
```

I receive:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

d

db4

Instead of:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

d

db

Comment: `%s` means string and C strings are null-terminated. `pass` must be of size 3, with the last element being 0. Otherwise, you'll get UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings represented as character arrays, need to be null terminated. This includes your `abc` and `pass` arrays.  `printf` doesn't know anything about the size of your array when `abc` is passed to it. It just prints characters starting at that address until it hits a `\0` char.  Ditto for `pass`

If  `abc` was printing correctly without a null char appended to it, that that's probably just you getting lucky.  It's technically undefined behavior.

Let's fix your code up....

```
int main(void)
{
    char abc[52+1]; // 53
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        if (i < 26)
        {
            abc[i] = 'a' + i;
        }
        else
        {
            abc[i] = 'A' + i - 26;
        }
    }
    abc[52] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", abc);

    char pass[2+1]; //3
    pass[0] = abc[3];
    pass[1] = '\0'; // null terminate pass before printing
    printf("%s\n", pass);

    pass[1] = abc[1];
    pass[2] = '\0'; // null terminate pass again before printing
    printf("%s\n", pass);
}
```

Comment: It looks like a newbie error, it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @selbie I guess adding `abc[52+1]` is not really needed. You loop starting from `0` to less than `52`(0-51) and set the `abc[52] = '\0'.`

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud - not correct.  An array of size `52` has valid indices ranging from `0-51`, which the OP's `for` loop fills in with characters.  Without an increase in the array capacity, there would be no place to append the null char at the end.  Now do you understand why the `+1` is needed?